# Display IP address in panel ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-mate, ip

I need to display my ip address in my ubuntu panel and it's doable when you install giplet, but from what I understand, `giplet` is no longer supported by GNOME3.

Is there another way to display my ip address in the panel shown below?
[image]

I'm using ubuntu mate release 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 3):

This is simply possible by adding **Command Applet** to MATE Panel with corresponding **Command** inside - use something like `hostname -I`

[image: Command Applet]

or some [scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13322485/937095).

To add applet to MATE Panel you need to do right mouse click on top or bottom MATE Panel and then select *Add to Panel* menu item:

> [image: Add to Panel, Command]

To install the applet use `sudo apt-get install mate-applets` .

Comment: Thank you but I didn't figure out how to find the Command Applet, how can I launch this application?

Comment: You need to make right mouse click on top or bottom *MATE Panel* and then select *Add to Panel* item.

Comment: there is no Command Applet, is it installable?

Comment: Install it with `sudo apt-get install mate-applets` and please ensure that you are really using MATE desktop.

Comment: thank you, but it's already installed, so is there a command that enables me to launch the Command Applet from the terminal?

Comment: Its executable is in `/usr/lib/mate-applets/command-applet`, but it cannot be called directly . I would recommend to reinstall the package by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mate-applets`, then logout and login again to add the applet.

Comment: I did, but then when I right click on the panel -> add to panel, it's still not there